# IIS/ASP.Net vs NodeJs/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, asp.net, iis, nodes

I'm very new to NodeJs/expressJs, i read tons of articles on internet and still don't understand it

is NodeJs a web server like IIS ? if so can i host an asp.net app in NodeJS ?

Is expressJs a framework like ASP.NET ?

Comment: Node.js is similar to .NET (so it is not a web server), while Express is similar to ASP.NET.

Comment: NodeJs is not a web server. So NodeJS cannot host asp.net. ExpressJs is a framework  like ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I currently work on both IIS ASP.NET applications as well as NodeJS/ExpressJS systems and the below is what I have noted to be different:

IIS:

- Windows server based
- Can have strict setups such as MVC etc
- Built in deployment that compiles the entire website
- Setup can take quite some time to create all modals and get all
  plugins working etc
- Services can take some time setup and modal mapping can be tedious

NodeJS/ExpressJS:

- Not Windows based. I run this typically on an Ubuntu server with
  Nginx to push the domain to the public
- Easy to setup and fast to get something basic online
- Does not natively compile and runs files as they are
- Uses npm package manager with easy to install packages
- Does not have strict setups but you can technically create your own
  MVC style system
- Code can quickly become messy however with the correct approach you
  can manage the amount of code easily.

NodeJS is not a web server. It is a backend server (Such as a REST API etc)
ExpressJS sits ontop of NodeJS to add functionality and is essentially a framework. Coupled with jade/pug you can write js inside the html.